# recover files from newer time machine backup after restore to older state

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I have recently restored my machine's state (December) to an older state (November), but forgot to save a couple files from December.  When I go into Time machine the December state is not available, but those backups were definitely made.  How do I get the December files onto the November state of the machine?

Comment: this is confusing, newer/older/newer ...can you use numbers/dates

Comment: lol sure........